# Can a subscriber and publisher co-exist in a single nodelet?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a need to implement a nodelet that subscribes for messages from a topic, process them and then publish to another topic.

Can this be done using a single nodelet?

---

Edit: I tried the below demo, but see only publishing msgs. Sub's callback are not invoked.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace composition
{

// Create a Talker "component" that subclasses the generic rclcpp::Node base class.
// Components get built into shared libraries and as such do not write their own main functions.
// The process using the component's shared library will instantiate the class as a ROS node.
Peter::Peter()
: Node("peter"), count_(0)
{
  // Create a publisher of "std_mgs/String" messages on the "chatter" topic.
  pub_ = create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("chatter");

  // Use a timer to schedule periodic message publishing.
  timer_ = create_wall_timer(1s, std::bind(&Peter::on_timer, this));

  // Create a callback function for when messages are received.
  // Variations of this function also exist using, for example, UniquePtr for zero-copy transport.
  auto callback =
    [this](const typename std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg) -> void
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str())
      std::flush(std::cout);
    };

  // Create a subscription to the "chatter" topic which can be matched with one or more
  // compatible ROS publishers.
  // Note that not all publishers on the same topic with the same type will be compatible:
  // they must have compatible Quality of Service policies.
  auto sub_ = create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("chatter", callback);
}

void Peter::on_timer()
{
  auto msg = std::make_shared<std_msgs::msg::String>();
  msg->data = "Peter is here: " + std::to_string(++count_);
  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", msg->data.c_str())
  std::flush(std::cout);

  // Put the message into a queue to be processed by the middleware.
  // This call is non-blocking.
  pub_->publish(msg);
}

}  // namespace composition

#include "class_loader/class_loader_register_macro.h"

// Register the component with class_loader.
// This acts as a sort of entry point, allowing the component to be discoverable when its library
// is being loaded into a running process.
CLASS_LOADER_REGISTER_CLASS(composition::Peter, rclcpp::Node)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286784/can-a-subscriber-and-publisher-co-exist-in-a-single-nodelet?/) by [petermp](https://answers.ros.org/users/34323/petermp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-28**:
I've removed my answer as I'd missed the `ros2` tag. The use of the term `nodelet` made me think you were asking about the ROS1 concept.

Note: there are no 'nodelets' in ROS2, only nodes.

**Comment by [petermp](https://answers.ros.org/users/34323/petermp/) on 2018-03-28**:
Thanks. I am new to the forum and apparently made some edit mistakes.

I am able to get the code working and confirm that we can do both publishing and subscribing in any order using a single nodelet (in dynamic load composition example).

Peter

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-28**:
What's missing here is the declaration of the class. I believe the bug is that `pub_` is member of the class and therefore persists after the constructor, but the subscription `sub_` is local to the constructor and is destroyed when it is finished. You must keep the `sub_` to get callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to publish, subscribe, use services in composed nodes the same way you do with regular nodes.
Unfortunately the code sample you provided is not enough to help you (and the formatting make it hard to read).
How do you compose your nodes? how do you invoke them ?

If it helps, I pushed an example of Node that publishes and subscribes [here](https://github.com/mikaelarguedas/examples/commit/e7de8bb3e983ec1207b04a778a8b76c9592f58ea)
The main is creating an executor and adding the node to it. To compose more nodes in that process you would need to add more node like it's done in [the composition example](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/56dc5dedfbf098422414ed4c6711b69e8321c258/rclcpp/minimal_composition/src/composed.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1